# spring boot wont able to compaile jsp problem

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I am using spring boot and front end jsp and jQuery and maven . the project working fine .but jsp page is not compile. can any one explain I missed any maven dependency in pom.xml.
I have configured Spring Boot using annotations.
I have the following files
1)AppStarter class for configuring spring boot

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>merchant</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>merchant</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <groupId>com.merchantportal</groupId>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <wildfly.timeout>30000</wildfly.timeout>
        <wildfly.startupTimeout>30000</wildfly.startupTimeout>
        <poi.version>4.1.2</poi.version>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Http Client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- JSTL tag lib push test ll -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.18</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId> <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId> 
            <scope>runtime</scope> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.4</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>1.9</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-spring-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Tomcat for JSP rendering -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jstl for jsp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xalan/xalan -->
        <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis/axis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.51</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcpg-jdk15on -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpg-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.47</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>backport-util-concurrent</groupId>
            <artifactId>backport-util-concurrent</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Excel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.18</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ajaxtags</groupId>
            <artifactId>ajaxtags</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.iban4j/iban4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.iban4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>iban4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            </plugin> 
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
2020-12-08 19:17:06.422  INFO 3332 --- [  restartedMain] c.v.merchantportal.config.MainApp        : Started MainApp in 44.877 seconds (JVM running for 46.902)
org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler$SilentExitException
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler.exitCurrentThread(SilentExitExceptionHandler.java:90)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.immediateRestart(Restarter.java:181)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.initialize(Restarter.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.initialize(Restarter.java:562)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:67)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:45)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
    at com.vTransact.merchantportal.config.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:49)
2020/12/08 19:17:06,443 ERROR {}   ||  || line No :54 ||  :: Exception Occured:: org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler$SilentExitException ||  ||  ||  ||  
``
```

Comment: Post a screenshot or error log of Exception you are getting be clear.

Comment: @AkshayJain i attached exception .can you check and please help me